# How to cd to a directory with a name starting with a "-" (minus)?

Tags: terminal, folders

We have some folders where the names are starting with a "-". If I try to enter them with terminal, `cd` interprets the "-" as an option. How could I manage this?

Comment: One would be wise to avoid such characters in directory/folder names.

Comment: Couldn't you just do `cd '-my-directory'`?

Comment: @oldbunny2800 Did you try that?

Comment: @OldBunny2800 No. Quotes prevent the shell from treating characters separately; strings starting with hyphens are treated as options (or not) by the command that *receives* the arguments, regardless of how those strings were presented to the shell.

Comment: @patrix I did right after I posted the comment, then got distracted by other terminal shenanigans, then forgot about my comment. :)
Chepner ohhh, that makes more sense.

Answer (score 20):

This should just work:

```
cd /path/to/-folderthatstartswithdash
```

**EDIT**:

According to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/462739/how-to-cd-into-a-directory-with-this-name-2-starting-with-the-hyphen), this works if you only want to input the name:

```
cd -- -folderthatstartswithdash
```

Comment: The `--` method is the correct answer... it will work with most standard utilities that accept a filename as an argument and saves having to fully qualify the path.

Comment: The `--` method works as it "turns off" argument parsing.

Comment: Why the restriction "if you only want to input the name"? If you need more arguments, just put them before the `--`.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I'm just saying if you don't want the full path you can use this one. All other arguments should go before the --.

Answer (score 19):

```
cd ./-folder
```

usually works quite well here (and also with other commands)

Comment: One nice thing about this solution is that it works with any program or command, not just 'cd'; it does not depend on the command or program having any special behavior like "--" to turn change the interpretation of subsequent arguments.

Answer (score -5):

Putting the name in quotes should work.

Comment: Why would that work? How is the utility going to know the difference? Quoting is done by the shell, after all, the arguments array the utility receive will be *exactly the same* either way. I admit that I didn't try your solution, but from what little I know about shells, it seems pretty self-evident, that this *cannot possibly* work.

Comment: This should work on Windows IIRC, and is what I thought of first, but I can confirm that it doesn't work on mac.

Comment: If it works on Windows that's only because Windows' command line model is utterly ridiculous and inconsistent. Or just because Windows commands aren't treating `-` as an option character. But there's no way quoting should be able to change this behavior.